# Caffeine cache X509Certificate

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine-cache

I'm developing an option in one project that encrypts some data using X509Certificate. This project uses Spring Boot. I do encryption with BouncyCastle library.

To encrypt data I have to download recipient's certificate from some server. That's simple, I use Apache HttpClient. But frequent downloads can put a heavy load on the server, so I want to cache this certificate.

I have two methods:

```
public X509Certificate getFromServer() {
    // do some actions...
}
```

This method downloads certificate from server

```
public boolean isRevoked(X509Certificate cert) {
    // do some actions...
}
```

This method checks if a certificate has been revoked.

My goal is cache **getFromServer** method.
I need to set up cache eviction policy, that:

1. Evicts certificate if it has expired.
2. Evict certificate if it has revoked.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could use [Caffeine.expireAfter(expiry)](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#time-based) to write a custom policy. The [CacheLoader](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population#loading) can return `null` if the fetched certificate is revoked, or you might return an `Optional` and use negative caching to avoid miss storms for revoked certs. You'll likely benefit by using the native APIs as Spring's Cache abstraction is limited and intended only for the most simple use-cases.